# Iterate comparison - How can I write this better?

Tags: vb.net, strings

I would like to write the following piece of code cleaner and more efficient, any comments will be greatly appreciated:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = SomeDataTable
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim myColumn As String = dr("column").Trim().ToUpper()
        For Each group As String In collection
            If (group.Trim().ToUpper() = myColumn) Then
               'Add some logic here
            End If
        Next`
```

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use ToUpper() for case-insensitive string compares unless you're positive there will never be localized versions of your application (see: http://www.mattryall.net/blog/2009/02/the-infamous-turkish-locale-bug)

Comment: This is not C# code.

Comment: I am not a BASIC speaker, but I feel the last 4 lines do nothing.

Comment: @M.Sameer - Thanks for changing it to VB,NET
@Ingo - I updated the example to be more descriptive

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a VB.Net developer, but if I were writing this in C# I would use the Contains method on your collection. I'm assuming that your collection is a list of strings in this case.

I've included what the code might look like in VB.Net below. I give no guarantees that it works though. :)

```
Dim dt As DataTable = SomeDataTable

For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim myColumn As String = dr("column").ToString().Trim()

    If collection.Contains(myColumn, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
        'Do your stuff here
    End If
Next
```

Comment: +1 but to use Contains in this fashion (works in 4.0 only) it needs to be `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. `StringComparison` will fail the overload.

Comment: @Joel Etherton, ah I missed that when I was typing it out. Thanks for catching it. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two concerns with the code presented. If you can guarantee that you won't ever need localization and that the strings in `collection` will ALWAYS be upper case then you could use something like this:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = SomeDataTable

For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    'I always recommend explicitly calling .ToString() first
    'In response to @Mr. Disappointment's comment - he is right
    'Null check this first
    If Not dr.IsNull("column") Then 
        Dim myColumn As String = dr("column").ToString().ToUpper().Trim()

        If collection.Contains(myColumn) Then
            'Do your stuff here
        End If
    End If
Next
```

However, if these things are not guaranteed, then you are better off foregoing `.Contains` and using your own for loop (which is what `.Contains` will end up using anyway):

```
Dim dt As DataTable = SomeDataTable
```

There are two concerns with the code presented. If you can guarantee that you won't ever need localization and that the strings in `collection` will ALWAYS be upper case then you could use something like this:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = SomeDataTable

For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    'I always recommend explicitly calling .ToString() first
    'In response to @Mr. Disappointment's comment - he is right
    'Null check this first
    If Not dr.IsNull("column") Then 
        Dim myColumn As String = dr("column").ToString().Trim()

        For each group as String in collection
            If group.Equals(myColumn, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                'Do your stuff here
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: _'always recommend explicitly calling .ToString() first'_: Without checking for a `null` reference? Things go BANG! that way. You can use `dr.IsNull("column")` to check.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Tru dat. In my own code I would never use tables in this manner so my null checks would be handled differently, but you're absolutely right. A null check is highly advisable here.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Edit/credit added.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: A check for `null` is required / highly advisable in **any** case where a `NullReferenceException` might occur. To be fair, we're not talking about your code, but rather code you're offering to somebody as an improvement to their own - if you have thoughts on the issue then present them, please don't omit them.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: Better. Now just declare the `String` variable once outside of the loop and re-use it. ;)

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Ok, seriously the tone of your last comment is not appreciated. I was agreeing with your comment, and I adjusted my answer in line with that. In my original answer I hadn't considered null checks there because that's not where I handle those kinds of things in my code.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: In this case, the scope of the variable is highly irrelevant. The difference in reusing the variable vs re-dimming it in this case is negligible. If you want to take optimization to that level, you should recommend usage of the `StringBuilder` class.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: My concern isn't really for optimising in terms of speed, but productivity and readability - even this is negligible and hence my -wink- to convey such as somewhat tongue-in-cheek.